# Assemblies not loading in office add-in with .net 4

Tags: .net, vsto, office-interop, shim, fuslogvw

When I upgrade my add-in project from .net 3.5 to 4.0 I get this error in FusLog when it wants to load my add-in assembly:

> Error extracting manifest import from file (hr = 0x8013101b).

I also add this to office exe config file (visio.exe.config in my case) but nothing changed.

```
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Maybe also [providing the `sku` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would help? Like e.g. `sku=".NETFramework, Version=v4.0"`.

Comment: No, Same error with sku :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to reproduce the issue with a newly created add-in if the target framework is set to .net 4.0?

It looks like one of your dependencies cannot be loaded (i.e. the .net 4.0 runtime is not supported).

P.S. When we talk about .net 4.0 - the full edition of the .net framework is considered (not the Client Profile).

Comment: I get the issue any time I activate the add-in. I installed full edition of .net 4.0

Comment: Yes. When I build my new add-in under framework 4.0 I get this error.

Comment: What Visio/Office version do you have installed on the PC? Visual Studio?

Comment: My VS is 2013. I tried on both visio 2007 on XP and visio 2010 on windows 7.

Comment: @dan: if that fixed it, please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find the answer:
I should add useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" as a startup attribute of the config file.
so I should set the visio.exe.config to :

```
 <configuration>
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
   <supportedRuntime version="4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
 </startup>
 </configuration>
```